# Null pointer exception occured only when running the jar file - Scala Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jar, sbt

I have a Big-data analysis project. I used Spark for it and wrote using Scala.

When I ran the project using `sbt run` it worked perfectly and gave the results what I want.
After that I built the jar file using `sbt assembly` and ran it using `java -jar my.jar` .
But process stopped and gave me a null pointer exception.

Can anyone explain me why this happened? please.

I attached the stack trace for reference.

```
2019-06-15 18:49:56 DEBUG BlockManager:58 - Getting local block broadcast_0
2019-06-15 18:49:56 DEBUG BlockManager:58 - Level for block broadcast_0 is StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
2019-06-15 18:49:57 INFO  CodecPool:179 - Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
2019-06-15 18:49:57 DEBUG TaskMemoryManager:427 - unreleased 8.0 MB memory from org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.VariableLengthRowBasedKeyValueBatch@43d7b5b2
2019-06-15 18:49:57 DEBUG TaskMemoryManager:427 - unreleased 256.0 KB memory from org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@6aee5557
2019-06-15 18:49:57 DEBUG TaskMemoryManager:434 - unreleased page: org.apache.spark.unsafe.memory.MemoryBlock@3517be49 in task 0
2019-06-15 18:49:57 DEBUG TaskMemoryManager:434 - unreleased page: org.apache.spark.unsafe.memory.MemoryBlock@295da0ba in task 0
2019-06-15 18:49:57 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.createInputStream(GzipCodec.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(generated.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(generated.java:587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-06-15 18:49:57 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl:58 - parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
2019-06-15 18:49:57 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.createInputStream(GzipCodec.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(generated.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(generated.java:587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: with out full stack no one can tell about the error. stack trace pls!

Answer (score 1):

Spark applications should be started using spark-submit.
See [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html#spark_yarn_sparkpi_example)

So what you should do is to package your application (jar) and use spark-submit to run that jar in a spark context.

Sbt either detected your spark application (depending on your sbt settings) or it just ran your main method as a simple scala application ( again, depending on your settings).

Anyway, that's all I can say with the provided information. Please provide more info in order to get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It cleared some doubts. I edited the question by attaching stack trace.

Comment: well, you will have to provide the whole source code. As far as I can see spark is not able to read from one of your provided files .